# Удалить выборочные строки из файла по символу

Tags: python, строки

Всем здравствуйте, задача состоит в том чтобы либо удалить все строки либо их вообще не считывать.

Есть определенные категории в которых есть ненужные нам строки, как реализовать так чтобы допустим категория "invit" в ней данные "D", "F", "I", "Q", "B", нужно удалить строки с данными "Q" или не считывать строки в данной категории с данными строками.

Ситуация складывается так что при удалении всех строк с Q выходной файл получается не правильный. Как не брать эту строку для дальнейших манипуляций

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант - проверять каждую строку на соответствие определённому регулярному выражению. В зависимости от результата: сохранять эту строку в выходном файле или нет.

Пример кода (все строки входного файла, начинающиеся с символа `Q` будут исключены):

```
import re
import os

pattern = re.compile(r"^Q.*")

fin  = open(input_filename)
fout = open(output_filename, "w")

for line in fin.readlines():
      if not pattern.match(line):
              fout.write(line)

fin.close()
fout.close()

os.rename(output_filename, input_filename)
```

Вам оставляю составить подходящее регулярное выражение, обработать исключительные ситуации, по необходимости оптимизировать чтение/запись.

Comment: Ситуация складывается так что при удалении всех строк с Q выходной файл получается не правильный. Как не брать эту строку для дальнейших манипуляций

Comment: Вы приведите пример файла и укажите какие строки хотите исключить.

Answer (score 0):

```
# если файл вида
'''
[TEST]
Q2=http://handler/
[invit]
A=[123]
D=https:/
F=http://
 ...
'''

import configparser

def get_ini_data(file):
    parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
    parser.read(file)

    for category in parser.sections():
        for var in parser.options(category):
            if not (category == 'invit' and var in ["d", "f", "i", "q", "b"]):
                data = parser.get(category, var)
                yield category, var, data

for category, var, data in get_ini_data('test.ini'):
    print(category, var, data)
```